# Fixing Ubuntu USB-C to HDMI DELL DA200

Tags: kernel, dell, hdmi

Has been almost a year that I bought my dell xps developers edition with the DA200 adapter, which only works with low resolutions due to a published bug. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/t/19999974

I have been doing research from time to time in order to see if there is a fix for the issue, but I still don't find a proper answer. I am already using the latest kernel version (4.10.0-35-generic) and gnome version.

It seems that on march a solution was released as a patch, https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9646451/, but I have not clue how to use this patch.

I am writing this here for two reasons;

1. First, of course someone knows how to apply this patch and can let us know.
2. Second, there are so many post related to this, but no proper solutions. Hopefully we can create one together.

I hope that someone know how to do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.4/

Then download (this is the kernel that worked for me)

```
linux-headers-4.13.4-041304_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_all.deb
linux-headers-4.13.4-041304-generic_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.13.4-041304-generic_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_amd64.deb
```

Then install:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.13.4-041304_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.13.4-041304-generic_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.13.4-041304-generic_4.13.4-041304.201709270931_amd64.de
```

Then restart (you can use the ui)

```
shutdown -r now
```

Reference:

https://askubuntu.com/a/888111

Comment: So you have the USB-C HDMI working properly ? Please tell me that you are not kidding !

Comment: you still need to select the proper kernel at boot if it's not the highest version or the default. Also, Ubuntu 18.04 has kernel 4.15 shipped and I have the issue on that kernel version. So does this work and does it too for you on 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 16.04, you'll probably need to wait a few more months for the next HWE kernel version to get backported to 16.04 (in the 16.04.4 release). You should probably file a bug on Launchpad against the kernel for the Ubuntu version you're on, and see if perhaps you can convince the kernel team to get it into a kernel update before the next HWE.

In the meantime, you could download the 17.10 beta image, and boot from a live USB to test if the kernel in the coming release has the fix already. Note that the patch referenced landed in master, after the 17.04 release, and so likely wasn't backported upstream to the older kernels, and may not be. The fix may be in the kernel that is going in 17.10 though (and which will be in 16.04.4 HWE update).

Comment: That is sad to hear but really helpful. I though that was just something that I could patch and use.

Comment: Well, if the patch applies cleanly to the current kernel version you have, you could build your own kernel with the patch (but you'd have to maintain and rebuild in case of any security updates from Ubuntu).