# HDMI monitor not detected (Ubuntu 20.04, Dell DA200 usb-c adapter supplies the HDMI port)

Tags: hdmi, external-monitor

I cannot detect my HDMI monitor on ubuntu 20.04 using a HDMI port provided by a usb-c adapter (Dell DA200).

There are similar questions such as [Fixing Ubuntu USB-C to HDMI DELL DA200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960720/fixing-ubuntu-usb-c-to-hdmi-dell-da200) and [Dell DA200 Adapter not working on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778824/dell-da200-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu?rq=1) where the answer is to update the kernel. However, I believe am already using a far newer kernel.

Ubuntu 20.04.3, kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic

Dell XPS 15 9500

Comment: Does the computer you're using the USB-C docking station with has USB-C with alternative modes? Probably better to [edit] the question and post brand/model and other relevant hardware specifications.

Comment: What does it mean to have alternative modes?  The computer is a XPS 15 9500, the docking station is Dell DA200 (the latter is probably more relevant and was already included in the question).

Comment: It means whether or not it support video output. Not all USB-C ports have it. The Dell XPS 15 9500 supports DisplayPort according the specifications. this is actually a lot more relevant than the docking itself, unless faulty it works, period. But the computer may not! Now, which graphics are you testing it with? It likely works only with the dGPU Nvidia. Have you installed Nvidia drivers and selected the Nvidia profile?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I am using nvidia-driver-470.

Comment: As for the profile, I don't think I changed anything in the nvidia settings (but I did change to the nvidia driver). I can find a nvidia application called Nvidia X server where the profile is set to performance mode.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 21.10 and external monitor through Dell DA200 is not always working. I mean at first time after reboot or after sleeping mode it works fine but after next reconnect doesn't.